# ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0xbd4 in each Process causing high Kernel CPU Load

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, cpu-usage

My system lags heavily which source I can't really identify. I've tried DPC latency monitor, Xperf and other tools to track down a particular driver or component which may affects all processes and/or disk IO to cause unnaturally high kernel CPU loads. This also is showing in a massive decrease in IOPS from my Samsung Evo 850 SSD ( got 2k-3k IOPS instead of the usually 85k). However sequential access seems to be not affected in the same way. 
Using Sysinterlals Process Explorer I get usually this picture:

[image]

There seems to be a Spinlock issue combined with ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access+0xbd4, but I'm not sure what could cause this. I tried to update Intel Rapid Storage drivers, deactivate sequentially other drivers, deactivated Windows Defender and other filesystem filterdrivers I know of but nothing changed this general behaviour.

Strange thing is that when booting in Safe Mode with networking the lag is gone. Also a dual boot on VHD installation on the system of Win10 has no lagging. So it must be a certain configuration issue which I haven't been able to track down yet. At least it seems to be Disk IO related. Maybe someone has a suggestion I didn't thought of.

Comment: Without proper debugging symbols, the stack trace is practically useless.

Comment: What would you recommend ? XPerf with debugging symbols did not show very different results at least for the windows functions.

Comment: share the ETL file so that I can look at it with WPA/xperfview

Comment: Hi Andre,  you can download a trace here: [Trace](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnlQCf0HInA3j7xJwxPh_hsV3LTHBg) . Use your name as pw.

Comment: Meanwhile I played back an older image on my system, so it's working mostly normal at the moment. Maybe I experience the point when its got worse after any update which happended between the past 5 months. I deleted the trace data since its useless now.

Comment: the link is not working for me. Also notify me that you replied via @ my username

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry, as I wrote I meanwhile played back an older image on the system which was working, so the trace was useless meanwhile. But thanks for the offered help.

Comment: I would still take a look at it, maybe I can see something to prevent it in the future.

Comment: @magicandre1981 : Hi, I've restored the [Trace](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnlQCf0HInA3j7xJ9sSj5osfBNHruw) so maybe you find something. I would be really interested in the cause since it cost me around a week to struggle with the system until I decided to restore. But probably the trace doesn't contain enough valid Information. ( Use your username to open the archive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU suage has nothing to do with `ntoskrnl.exe!__misaligned_access`. In the trace I see calls like *ntoskrnl.exe!**Vi**AvlCompareNode*, *ntoskrnl.exe!**Vf**DeadlockDeleteMemoryRange* or *ntoskrnl.exe!**Verifier**KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc*.

Those calls are called when you activate [Driver Verifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_Verifier). Driver Verifier adds a lot of additional checks to system calls which make Windows much slower.

So it looks like you had some Bugchecks/BSODs in the past and enabled Driver Verifier to debug it easier. [Disable it](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101379-driver-verifier-enable-disable.html#option2)

[image]

[image]

, reboot and your issues are gone.

Comment: Hey, that looks really good. That would have probably saved me a week. I indeed used the verifier for tracing some BSoD issues and the symbols looked to me like some tracing mechanism, but I wasn't sure that this also was Xperf related stuff being not masked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome. Next time share the ETL directly