# 'System' process pins 1 CPU/thread at 100%

Tags: cpu, windows-11, high-cpu-usage

I have a Dell XPS 9500 laptop, 6 cores/12 threads.

Recently I noticed that the system task is constantly running around 18% CPU, and as shown in the attached picture, it's actually consuming 100% of 1 thread.  The CPU Speed is also pinned at 4+GHz.  Obviously, this also drains the battery very quickly too.

[image: Task manager CPU]

[image: Task manager Processes]

I've tried the scannow/dism suggestions, and whilst it repaired a few things, it's not fixed this issue.

I've run ProcessExplorer and Properties/Threads show that all the CPU time is in `ntoskrnl.exe!KeInitializeApc+0x4c0`

Any suggestions to help fix this would be gratefully received.

Comment: DISM/SFC may not have fixed the problem. I suggest doing [Startup Repair](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/use-startup-repair-in-windows-11.14660/).

Comment: There is someone reportimg that a GPU driver update resolved the issue : https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/precision-mobile-workstations/many-users-reporting-parasitic-system-process-after-recent-update/65bd7a9942e0c52e7e185c8b  Also, it seems to be specific to Dell machines

Comment: Yes, I got a fix last night.  NVidia driver update appears to fix it.